# ASP.NET Get FileUpload object from its ID on codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say my fileUpload id is "fuID" and it's defined on my ASCX file.

How do I get the FileUpload object in my codebehind (cs) using its Id?

As:

```
    public voiattachA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fuid = hiddenItemIndex; // which is the "fuID" string
        FileUpload fu; // = something using its ID
    }
```

Thanks in advence

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your code behind is on a page which use that user control which contains file upload control you want

You can get it by：

```
public voiattachA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fuid = hiddenItemIndex; // which is the "fuID" string
    // get instance of the custom control by id
    var objTestControl = (UserControlType)Page.FindControl("yourUserControlID");
    // find the file upload control in the custom control by id
    FileUpload fu = objTestControl.FindControl(fuid) as FileUpload;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, it helped me then but I totally forgot to say thanks lol.

Comment: @ArnaldoLucien 
glad it helped.  
It would be great if you can mark it as answer so when other search can see clearly it worked for you.